# Hide object if text is detected in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

im trying to hide object if a text is detected in the address bar,

my url looks like this sample.com/view=entry&id=8&lid=179 (when &id=8 is detected it should hide alse if if id=19 show something alse

found something that may work but needs adjustments

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 var ZnodeSitename = 'http://example.com'; 
 if (window.location.search.substring(1) == "id=8") {
     var objFrame = document.getElementById("frame1");

 }
 else if (window.location.search.substring(1) == "id-9") {
     var objFrame = document.getElementById("frame1");
 }
 else {
     var objFrame = document.getElementById("id-9");
     var objFrame = document.getElementById("frame1");

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure JavaScript, try using this code below

**JavaScript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    var frame = document.getElementById("frame1");

    // Assuming "?id=8"

    if (getUrlParameter('id') == '8') {
        frame.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        frame.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function getUrlParameter(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
        var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
        var results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    };

    // getUrlParameter('post'); // "1234"

</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="frame1">
    <p>Will This Be Hidden</p>
</div>
```